# Can I exclude a package from being automatically updated by NUGET?

Tags: nuget, umbraco, nuget-package

In a project we have Umbraco 7.3.4 and it has a dependency for JSON.NET <= 6.0.8. When I'm trying to install other 3rd party packages which require JSON.NET >= 8.0.0, this forces Umbraco to automatically update to version 7.4, which I don't want.

Putting aside considerations of pros and cons of making a hack, I am happy to do a hack because I know that Umbraco works with JSON.NET 8.0.0. The question is how to disable in Nuget automatic update (dependency resolving) only for the Umbraco package? In an ideal case (and much better one) I would only want to ignore JSON.NET dependency for Umbraco package, but let Nuget update Umbraco package if any other cross-dependency update requires this.

Many thanks for an advice

Answer (score 0):

This isn't an Umbraco feature but a Nuget feature, you can include the flag `-IgnoreDependencies` but it's not selective as far as I am aware. Beware you may well miss other dependencies that could cause you to end up in dependency hell!

Example:

`Update-Package Newtonsoft.Json -Version 8.0.0 -IgnoreDependencies`

Nuget Documentation:

```
-IgnoreDependencies
    Installs only this package and not its dependencies.

    Required: false
```

See https://docs.nuget.org/consume/package-manager-console-powershell-reference

Warning: Backup your project before attempting this so you can roll it back in the event of a problem!

Comment: This will add JSON.NET 8.0.0 to solution, however when I try adding another package then Nuget runs another check of dependencies and forces either to upgrade Umbraco or add the package ignoring all dependencies. The management of this becomes sort of a problem. In the end Nuget is doing what is supposed to do, but in this instance it would be helpful to ignore JSON.NET dependency for Umbraco package (and only this one)

Comment: In that case perhaps you need to not use Nuget for this particular dependency.

Comment: this is as far as I got to, but it is not a solution unfortunately.